# Do we need to specify catalogs.properties file same in both presto coordinator and worker?

Tags: presto

Well, I have two docker containers one of Presto coordinator and one for Presto Worker. It works fine but I need to specify the catalogs.properties files same in both coordinator and worker

Although my presto worker doesn't need to know about my catalogs.properties files they can fetch the details from master itself
But if I didn't specify then my presto launcher gets failed

Is there any way to stop the duplicity of  catalogs.properties file in both master and slave

Answer (score 1):

No, currently you need to configure your catalogs on each machine.

Note: in a typical production setup there will be some automation doing this for you, so there manual work is not multiplied then.

Answer (score 0):

you may see this , it has configuration of presto on how to automatically make sure all workers have same catalog file. Note , this is just one of the features
https://github.com/niths4u/prestodb-cluster/